# PHP variable to JavaScript variable to HTML span

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get a random question in 1 file (a PHP file), and getting that question in another file (a HTML file) that doesn't support PHP. Do you have any idea why/what isn't working?

This is what I already tried:

```
<?php
    $q = "How much is 5 plus 4?";
?>

<script>
    var qu = <?php echo $q; ?>;
    document.getElementById("quest").innerHTML = this.qu;
</script>

<span id="quest"></span>
```

Thank you.

**ANSWER**

```
<span id="quest"></span>

<?php
    $q = "How much is 5 plus 4?";
?>

<script>
    var qu = "<?php echo $q; ?>";
    document.getElementById("quest").innerHTML = this.qu;
</script>
```

Thank you for fixing it :)

Comment: Try quotes, `var qu = How much..;` is not a valid expression

Comment: Hint: When you `echo $q`, does it output the quotation marks that JavaScript needs for representing a string?

Comment: `var qu = '<?php echo $q; ?>';` notice the js variable needs to be wropped in quotes

Comment: any console errors???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you are grabbing an element that might not exist yet.  You want to move that script to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

first : you have to put `javascript` after element.

second :  quotes the variable

```
<span id="quest"></span>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    var qu = "<?php echo $q; ?>";
    document.getElementById("quest").innerHTML = 'dsfsd';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 var qu = "<?php echo json_encode($q); ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the javascript variable in quotes like :
     
    var qu = "?php echo $q ?>";